# Why pandas.read_parquet only use one CPU?

Tags: dask, parquet, cpu-usage, pyarrow

I'm using `pandas.read_parquet` to read about 66GB from s3 into memory on a SageMaker instance `ml.g5.24xlarge`. I use `engine='pyarrow'`, and `use_threads=True`. It took about 8 mins to finish. When I checked CPU usage for the process, I found the CPU never exceeds 200%, although the instance has 96 CPUs. I print out `pyarrow.io_thread_count()`, it is 8. I tried to `pa.set_io_thread_count(32)`, but nothing happened, the reading still took 8 mins, and CPU still not more than 200%.

If I use `pyarrow.parquet.read_table`, it is same as using `pandas.read_parquet`. I'm wondering if there is a way to make pandas or pyarrow.parquet to read faster.

If I use `dask.dataframe.read_parquet`, no surprise, it only took 2m28s and CPU use was about 600%, io_thread_count=8. If I set `pyarrow.set_io_thread_count(32)`, it used 1m42s, CPU reached ~1000%. I use pyarrow as engine for dask. Why can dask use more CPUs?

Here are the packages:

```
dask                      2023.6.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2023.6.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.23.5          py310h53a5b5f_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.0.1           py310h7cbd5c2_1    conda-forge
pyarrow                   12.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.8          h4a9ceb5_0_cpython    conda-forge
```

I used Amazon SageMaker 'PyTorch 2.0 Python 3.10 GPU Optimized' image and use `mamba install faiss-gpu dask more-itertools` to install faiss and dask.

Comment: Can you check the versions of the packages and add them to the question? (can help with reproducing this behaviour)

Comment: where does the data come from? s3? disk? You could be IO bound rather than CPU bound.

Comment: Update the question with package information. The parquet files are in a S3 bucket.   I don't think pandas or pyarrow use io_thread_count threads to read the parquet files, but limit to one CPU (two hyper threads).

Comment: As you are doing only IO, it is possible that the bandwith is slowing you down, so with Dask, even if you have many threads running, they're all waiting for IO and doing nothing.